# upload image reactjs / nodejs error

Tags: node.js, forms, reactjs, express, axios

Hi I'm trying to upload an image with reactjs, when I upload the image in console.log from nodejs. I get an empty array
Any suggestions

component reactjs

```
export default class Categoria extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state= {}
        this.handleSubmit=this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
    }   

    render(){
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}  encType="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="file" onClick={this.handleImageChange.bind(this)}   name="photo" />
                <button type="submit">upload picture </button>
            </form>                  
        )
    }
    handleImageChange(e) {
        this.setState({photo: e.target.files[0]});              
    }
    handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        axios.post("x/photos", this.state.photo)
        .then((response) =>{
            console.log(response.data)
        })
        .catch((err)=>{
          console.log(err)
        })
    }
}



// router nodejs 
router.post('/x/photos', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body.photo)
}
```

Comment: what do you get in the axios then response?

Comment: I get a good message, the problem is reactjs. Why test with a form in an html and work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you will get an image like `req.body.photo`. Use `https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer` to upload documents

Comment: hi, thanks, the router update router.post('/x/photos', upload.single('photo'), function(req, res){
 console.log(req.file) } but the console log, show undefined, i think so, the problem is in react